# How can I select which column to use in a WHERE condition programmatically?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `table` which has three fields: `id`, `field1` and `field2`.

The SQL query I need to create should select the `id`s WHERE `field1 LIKE 'Some string'` but if `field1` is `NULL` I should perform the filtering against `field2`, in pseudo SQL:

```
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE (IF `field1` IS NULL THEN `field2` ELSE `field1`) LIKE 'Some string'
```

How can I achieve this in MySQL?

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of the [Flow Control Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull). You could write:

#### `CASE` operator (recommended)

```
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE CASE 
    WHEN `field1` IS NOT NULL THEN `field1`
    ELSE                           `field2`
END LIKE 'Some string'
```

#### `IF` construct

```
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE IF(`field1` IS NOT NULL, `field1`, `field2`) LIKE 'Some string'
```

#### `IFNULL` construct

```
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE IFNULL(`field1`, `field2`) LIKE 'Some string'
```

Comment: I guess you were the first, I will accept the answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
WHERE IFNULL(`field1`, `field2`) LIKE 'Some string'
```

Comment: I like this solution for not repeating the testes string twice like one would have to do with `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

With an or:

```
where (field1 like 'some_string' or (field1 is null and field2 like 'some_string'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OR:
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE `field1` LIKE 'Some string' OR `field2` LIKE 'Some string'